# POST using HttpClient to add to a list MailChimp API 3.0

Tags: c#, json, post, http-post, httpclient

Im trying to send a POST request to add a subscriber to a list to mail chimp using their 3.0 API. I send the request but the error I get back is a 405 - Method not allowed error which I do not understand how to fix.

I am using a Http Client to send a PostAsync request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        foreach (MailChimpSubscriberModel subscriber in newSubscribers)
        {
            Subscriber member = new Subscriber();
            member.email = subscriber.Email;
            member.subscribed = "subscribed";

            var url = "https://" + _dataPoint + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + _defaultListId + "/";
            string jsonString = jss.Serialize(member);

            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
            stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _apiKey);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);

            Trace.WriteLine("Response StatusCode: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MailChip API at http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/lists-instance

it doesn't look like /lists/{list_id} accepts POST requests which you are doing with PostAsync().

Comment: Hi @Dan, i am wanting to add a member to a list: http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-collection

Comment: your url is pointing to /lists/{list_id}, try
var url = "https://" + _dataPoint + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + _defaultListId + "/members";

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. I think the members refers to the json members object that I am wanting to add

Comment: No, "members" is definitely part of the URI http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-collection